# LINQ generic delegates in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, delegates

I got an exam question that I couldn't answer, looked up and couldn't find an answer either.

".NET uses which generic delegates in LINQ?"

Comment: What do you mean "which generic delegates"?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica - "do you mean" will be hard to answer for OP since OP isn't the one who wrote the question, that's why OP is struggling to find an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different versions of [`Func` delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netcore-3.1) are used in different [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/standard-query-operators-overview) methods. For example [`Enumerable.Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=netcore-3.1) has two different overloads that accept `Func<TSource, Boolean>` and `Func<TSource, Int32, Boolean>` respectively. You can go through [`Enumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=netcore-3.1) (or [`Queryable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable?view=netcore-3.1)) methods yourself, as far as I can see only `Func<T,TResult>` or `Func<T1,T2,TResult>` are used in standard query operations.

Answer (score -2):

Action
Func
Predicate
.net use this 3 delegates in Linq

Comment: Does it? Where?

Comment: @GertArnold - depends on the LINQ query you are using, in a `.Where` you are using an `Predicate` (returns boolean accepts `T` as an argument) - in a `.Select` you are using a Func (returns `T1` accepts `T` as an argument) - in a `.ForEach` you are using an `Action` (void and accepts `T` as an argument)

Comment: @RandRandom `ForEach` is not part of LINQ but method defined on `List<T>`  AFAIK.

Comment: Not `System.Predicate`. And `ForEach` isn't LINQ.

Comment: @GuruStron - sorry my bad, but I still hope my point gets accross even though I picked the wrong methods

Comment: @GertArnold - same response as to GuruStron

Comment: @RandRandom OK, it's not your answer, but nowhere does a LINQ method accept a `System.Predicate` object. A `Func<T,bool>` is a predicate semantically, not in a strict technical sense. I really don't understand how this answer can be upvoted, let alone accepted.

Comment: @GertArnold - well than maybe the answer to OPs question is only "Action Func" without the "Predicate", though I thought that as you said "Func<T,bool> is a predicate semantically" you could pass a `Predicate` to the method and it would implicit cast to `Func<T, bool>`, didn't know that this isn't the case, but IMHO if you feel like you can give OP a better answer just do so